# Chart.js displaying time data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to render an array of time data on the x axis scale of a line chart in chart.js but despite trying numerous options settings cannot get it to display at all.  The data is in string format ["00:30", "01:00", "01:30"...] and these are my xAxes options settings:

```
xAxes: [{
   type: "time",
   time: {
      parser: "hh:mm",
      unit: "minute",
      displayFormats: {
                  minute: "hh:mm"
      }
   },
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include moment.js?

Comment: Yes, moment.js is included.

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: Here's a working example - https://jsfiddle.net/dthory/upLd7t6j/3/ Seems like the array of time data i'm generating is not passing over to the ejs file as a string (i.e. as the variable timeData. When this is formatted to an array of strings - timeDataString  it works without having to implement time settings on the options, but I need to make it work with the timeData array - hope that make's sense! Thanks..

Comment: Didn't realize this was an old question, but if you mark my answer it would  probably help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that moment.js script tag should be placed early in the "script" tags in your example. It will work in your example if you do (also uncomment the "xaxis" section).

So put script tag above chart.js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

`

Here is also an easy way to represent whatever you would like in chart.js and get the data and do whatever you'd like (it will also help find your error):

```
xAxes: [{
   ticks: {
       callback: function(value) {
          //"HH:mm:ss"
          return moment(value).format("mm:ss");
       }
   }
}],
```